# how to build pixhawk application

Tags: toolchain, firmware, px4

I am new in building PIXHAWK application. I am following the Pixhawk Pilot Support Package (PSP) User Guide. But I receive an error in running `make px4fmu-v2_default` and finally I can't finish it.

> CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
>   couldn't find python module jinja2:

For debian systems I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install python-jinja2
```

or for all other OSs/debian:

```
pip install jinja2
```

> (missing: PY_JINJA2)
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:377 (FPHSAFAILURE_MESSAGE)
>
> cmake/common/px4_base.cmake:622 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
>   CMakeLists.txt:293 (px4_find_python_module)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>   See also "C:/pixhawk_toolchain/Firmware/build_px4fmu-v2_default/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>
> rm: cannot remove directory `/c/pixhawk_toolchain/Firmware/build_px4fmu-v2_default': Permission denied
>
> make: *** [px4fmu-v2_default] Error 1

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu it can be

```
 sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try:

```
pip install -U Jinja2
```